# Qt Gui for serial communication

Tags: qt, serial-port, arm, embedded-linux, u-boot

I am learning Qt and I wanted to create a GUI with some buttons which sends data to boot my ARM device through serial console (instead of minicom).
I know there is a serial communication library already provided by Qt.
I just wanted to know if this is a realistic approach to take at U-boot level? Or will I mess my data ? 
Just to visualize the requirement better :

```
button---->clicked()--->It should send 1st command to serial console as
"setenv bootargs blablabla" and then application should read back if 
we are getting back the prompt "U-boot#". If yes,then send the next command 
"tftp 0x82000000 uImage" and so on.
```

These commands can be in some text file.Though,I still have to think of the design and that's why i just wanted to know if its even possible?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: This question is really unclear, but if you are asking if `QSerialPort` is a good way to talk to hardware, then the answer is yes. I prefer it to platform specific approaches.

Comment: If you cite a program which can send and receive data through a serial port, whilst asking "is it even possible to write a program which sends and receives data through a serial port", what's left to answer? (funnily enough, just last week I wrote a script to do pretty much exactly this, for an automated git bisect run)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible, I have done that in my project, problem is reading result from the serial port,sometime you will get some junk characters so it is difficult to decide command issued is pass or failed, and qt window freezing issue when no activity is done within time-limit.

Comment: I suspect the same.  And that's what my question was.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To Qt4, use Qextserialport
From Qt5, use QSerialPort

Qextserialport & QSerialPort work on linux and windows with the same code.

Answer (score -2):

On windows, there is a part of WinAPI that can handle the serial communication and I think it can be used with Qt as any other C/C++ library.

Note that for this to work, your device has to appear as COM port in your device manager.

On linux, there is a C library called termios, but I have no experience with it so far.

[WinAPI serial communication tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx)

Comment: There is a Qt, cross platform approach called [QSerialPort](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html). There is _no reason_ to use the WinAPI if you already have a Qt dependency. Even if you are _only_ programming for Windows, `QSerialPort` is probably superior since you can use it asynchronously with signals and slots.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Qt, so I've offered what I've worked with until now. The `QSerialPort` interface looks really nice, maybe I should try that as well instead of WinAPI, thanks.

Comment: Thanks Guys for generous answers. I knew about the QSerialPort library.Just wanted to ask if we can use it this to communicate with freescale vybrid board at U-Boot level (to send commands at u-boot prompt) OR I can do it only at user space (when kernel and file system is loaded).